# How do I get rid of this extra battery icon?

Tags: unity, panel, icons

on Ubuntu 11.04 I had the battery-status indicator applet installed.  After the upgrade to Ubuntu 11.10 Beta I do not want to use the applet any longer. I deinstalled it, but I cannot get rid of the icon in the panel.

How can I delete the icon?

Screenshot:

[image]

Left one is the "old" one, right icon is the one from gnome-power-manager

Comment: Have you restarted the session after deinstalling the indicator? Also look in Startup Applications if it is called here.

Answer (score 1):

1. go to dash
2. type: power
3. Enter power management and choose "general" tab
   you'll see the option there.

Comment: there isnt this tab in 11.10 - this is the workaround for 11.04